# Maven dependency ambiquity

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have three application A1 , A2 and A3

- Build and Install A1 jar
- Add A1 in A2 pom.xml and Build
- Install A2

Now

if I include A2 in A3 pom.xml , will it fetch A1 also? it is not happening in my case. is this normal?

```
**A1 pom.xml**
<dependency>
<!--- some external jars -->
</dependency>


**A2 pom.xml**
<dependency>
  A1.jar
</dependency>

**A3 pom.xml**
<dependency>
  A2.jar
</dependency>
```

Will A3 pull A2 and A1 ? if not how to achieve that.

Comment: Do you mind post your .pom's? Are you includinf apps as external jar or as maven dependencies?

Comment: its a application jar.. edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So found out the solution. The trick is simple. ,

Follow the same `mvn install` command but just add the `pom.xml` along with it.

```
mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=file.jar" "-DgroupId=groupId" "-DartifactId=artifactId" "-Dversion=version" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-DpomFile=path/to/pom.xml"
```

Adding a new parameter **-DpomFile=path/to/pom.xml** should pull all the dependent jars used by parent.